# How do I manage rule-driven page flow?

Tags: workflow

I'm aware there are some methods (even frameworks) for managing business rules about page flow in an ASP.Net Web Applications with Workflow Foundation, but what about SharePoint applications?

Is there a way to manage rules in an elegant way with a SharePoint project? Specifically those relating to page flow.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly complex workflows can now be created using SharePoint Designer. If that is not sufficiently powerful you can build custom workflows using Visual Studio 2010.

To learn about the workflow capabilities in SharePoint you can start with [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff819861) or refer to one of several books about SharePoint 2010 workflows.